# Empty request from Google Smart Home SDK

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I'm creating web server to connect my DIY smart home devices to Google Home app.

After authorisation and token request Google server makes POST request to fullfillment URL, but request is empty for some reason. According to documentation, it must be SYNC request, but it does not contain any values, even request ID.

There is error "Couldn't  update the setting. Check your Internet connection." on my phone after request.

So why does it happen and how I can fix it?

```
const app=smarthome({ debug: true, });

app.onSync( async (body) => {
    return {
        requestId: body.requestId,
        payload: {
            agentUserId: "agentUserId",
            devices                       // devices list
        }
    };
});

server.post("/request", app);
```

Comment: Is the authorization token in the request header correct?

Comment: Yes, it comes 2 token requests to server and in fulfilment request token matches to last requested token.

Comment: Header includes all data, as `content-type`, `authorization` etc, but body is `undefined`

Comment: Can you revisit the console and make sure that your project is in a test state?

Comment: I'm not sure but it [looks like that](https://imgur.com/Pj0xOYC)

Comment: Can you disable and re-enable to see if anything changes?

Comment: I've disabled and re-enabled test and request's body is still `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to include `body-parser` 'cause I'm using general web server instead of `actions-on-google` API. LOL

Case closed.